# FirebaseAuth currentuser

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I run my Android app for the first time, FirebaseAuth.currentUser returns a weird DefaultFirebaseUser.
What is this user? I would expect the currentUser to be null.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
```

I searched online for answers, but I didnt find anything.
Thanks for the help!

Simone.

Comment: could you please share the implementation

Comment: It is just a line of code. I added it. Thanks

Comment: Can someone help me? =(